# How to rank a customer according to a next best offer model in SQL in case the customer is elegible for more than one product

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, ranking

I have a set of customers that are eligible for a certain type of products:

| Customer | Product |
| --- | --- |
| John | Banana |
| John | Apple |
| John | Orange |
| Carla | Banana |
| Carla | Apple |
| Carla | Orange |

I also have a model which tells me which products are most suited for the customer, based on his preferences:

| Customer | Most Suited Product | Second Most Suited Product | Third Most Suited Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Peach | Orange | Banana |
| Carla | Apple | Banana | Peach |

As you can see, there may be other products most suited, but they aren't eligible at the moment.

I'm running a campaign and I can only advertise two products per customer. This is down through an outbound sales team which requires me to have duplicates on my dataset.

How would I rank them according to their product most suited in order to have only two rows per customer?

I want this:

| Customer | Product | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John | Orange | 1 |
| John | Banana | 2 |
| Carla | Apple | 1 |
| Carla | Banana | 2 |

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: This *looks* like an unpivot with a `JOIN`. Whay *have* you tried? Why didn't it work.

Comment: I tried unpivoting, however I wasn't able to rank them according to their most suited product

Comment: Do you only have three products in your "ranked products table"? If so, you could just union them, once for each suit, adding a suitOrder (1,2, or 3 respectively) column to each subquery in the UNION/UNION ALL. Then do an EXISTS to remove those which are not in eligible products for that customer. Then do your rank on suitOrder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```sql
SELECT  customers.Customer, p.Product
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customers.Customer ORDER BY p.sort) AS rank
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'John', N'Banana')
    ,   (N'John', N'Apple')
    ,   (N'John', N'Orange')
    ,   (N'Carla', N'Banana')
    ,   (N'Carla', N'Apple')
    ,   (N'Carla', N'Orange')
) customers (Customer,Product)
INNER JOIN (
        VALUES  (N'John', N'Peach', N'Orange', N'Banana')
        ,   (N'Carla', N'Apple', N'Banana', N'Peach')
    ) products (Customer,[Most Suited Product],[Second Most Suited Product],[Third Most Suited Product])
    ON  products.Customer = customers.Customer
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES ([Most Suited Product], 1),([Second Most Suited Product],2),([Third Most Suited Product],3)
    ) p (product, sort)
WHERE   p.product = customers.Product
```

1. You join your Customer and Product table by customer Id.
2. Then pivot the products by their suitability.
3. Finally, join back by the pivoted product. The rank then becomes a simple ROW_NUMBER